# Using ES2015 Modules In TypeScript Without A Module Loader

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, typescript, npm

I have a TypeScript project that I would like to configure so it uses ES2015 modules without any module bundler like Browserify or Webpack.

[In the TypeScript compiler documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html), there is an option to specify which type of module is generated e.g. CommonJS, AMD, ES2015, etc. I have my option set to ES2015.

The problem I have is that the rendered JavaScript imports modules using the "./file" syntax instead of "./file.js" syntax. JavaScript modules in the browser must end in .js, otherwise a 404 not found error is generated.

The only solution I've found that works is to specify the "./file.js" syntax inside the TypeScript files themselves, which is incorrect.

What can I do to get the .js file extension for modules being imported in the rendered JavaScript files?

index.html

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <base href="/">
</head>
<body>
  <script type="module" src="./js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.ts

```
import { Cat } from './cat'
import { Dog } from './dog'

let cat = new Cat('Lily');
cat.eat();
cat.sleep();
cat.meow();

let dog = new Dog('Rex');
dog.eat();
dog.sleep();
dog.bark();
```

animal.ts

```
export class Animal {
  public readonly name: string;

  public constructor(
    name: string
  ) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public sleep(): void {
    console.log(`${this.name} is sleeping.`);
  }

  public eat(): void {
    console.log(`${this.name} is eating.`);
  }
}
```

cat.ts

```
import { Animal } from './animal'

export class Cat extends Animal {
  public meow(): void {
    console.log(`${this.name} is meowing.`);
  }
}
```

dog.ts

```
import { Animal } from './animal'

export class Dog extends Animal {
  public bark(): void {
    console.log(`${this.name} is barking.`);
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "http-server -a localhost -p 5000 -c-1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "ts-loader": "^6.0.4",
    "typescript": "^3.5.2"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES2015",
    "outDir": "js",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What can I do to get the .js file extension for modules being imported in the rendered JavaScript files?

Not much, see [this github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16577). You could write your own transform and use something like [ttypescript](https://github.com/cevek/ttypescript) instead of regular compiler.

> The only solution I've found that works is to specify the "./file.js" syntax inside the TypeScript files themselves, which is incorrect.

No it's not incorrect, it's what some members of TypeScript team [had recommended](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13422#issuecomment-275458975) and [some people are actually using](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13422#issuecomment-500172941). It works, in the sense that TypeScript will still look for and compile a `.ts` file if it exists, not `.js` file.

See also [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18442).

Another potential solution is to use [import maps](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps) and [import map generator](https://github.com/open-wc/open-wc/tree/master/packages/import-maps-generate) to map extensionless imports to URLs in the browser. However, it's still "spec in progress" and is [not yet implemented in all browsers](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5315286962012160).